# Closed on one vote?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderators

In relation to this:

[Dialog Node Error Jump to failed from node in Watson Assistant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56316405/dialog-node-error-jump-to-failed-from-node-in-watson-assistant)

Newbies first post was a little messy, but the issue was quite clear to anyone experienced in the topic.

Is it just a side effect of being a moderator? I feel a group vote would have resolved this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Is it just a side effect of being a moderator?

Yes, diamond moderators have binding close votes. That's why the question was closed with only one vote. A single vote by a moderator is enough to reach the threshold.

> I feel a group vote would have resolved this.

Group votes don't "resolve" anything. They just take longer and require more people's involvement to achieve the exact same result.

To resolve problems with questions, you use the edit feature, as you already have.

Your edit is a start, but it's still a "debug my code" question that doesn't show any code. Guessing at what the problem might be based on the error message is not particularly useful.

Comment: Group vote would mean those who follow the tag and know if it's a mess or not, fix question and possibly answer. A straight close prevents that from happening. but my question is answered. :) Although not sure why the downvotes.

Comment: Given the relative lack of quality that I've been seeing lately in the IBM Watson tags, and the apparent lack of standards among the followers of that tag, I'm not convinced that letting the community handle this one would have improved matters. Regardless, it seems that you misunderstand the purpose of closing. The reason questions get closed is to allow them to be edited into shape. You don't edit *before* closing; you edit *after* closing. I think the downvotes on this question are adequately explained by the tooltip: *"This question does not show any research effort..."*

Comment: While I agree with you somewhat, it's a new user. A straight close doesn't even remotely help them. A new user doesn't see the reason, they just see people being unhelpful.  Anyway, I have nothing further to add.

Comment: The age of the user doesn't matter. Moderation here is not focused on users, it is focused on content. Questions that are closed have a giant yellow banner appear underneath them, explaining both the reason for closure in detail *and* giving specific advice on how the question can be fixed to comply with our guidelines. While you may be correct that new users don't *care*, because they simply want an answer, that isn't a problem that we can solve. More to the point, selfish behavior like that isn't something that we should encourage by ignoring our quality standards and answering anyway.